# I can't understand why test is failing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I've looked at jest and enzyme documentation and don't know where else to find out how to do this.

Heres the test:

```
describe('The tile grid displays the tile container when there is no error and it is 
not loading', () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const defaultProps = {
      ...TileGridDefaultPropsInit,
 
    };
   wrapper = shallow(<TileGrid  {...defaultProps} />);

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
 });

  it('it displays the tile grid container', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find('.tile-grid__container')).toHaveLengthOf(1);
  });});
```

Heres the output from console.log(wrapper.debug())

```
    <div className="tile-grid">
          <div className="tile-grid__heading">
            Top Stories
          </div>
          <div className="tile-grid__container">
            // theres a load of stories here - too long to put paste onto this question.
            
           
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation from **Jest**, the method is actually called `toHaveLength`:

https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavelengthnumber

On the other hand, documentation from **Enzyme** uses `expect` from **Chai** assertion which has `to.have.lengthOf`

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html

Choose either **Jest** or **Chai** for writing this unit test.